# How can I increase the available space for the system in Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH2s5.png)

I have 34.4 GB of free space available, and I want to allocate this space to /dev/sdb5 in a usable way.

Comment: Boot from your install medium in "Try Ubuntu" mode. One cannot manipulate a disk's partitions while any one of the disk's partitions is mounted.

Comment: As you also may notice, you will have to move sda4 and sda5 to the front, before being able to expand sda5 into the free space. Moving partitions can be a slow process though and may fail. Make sure your backup is up to date before undertaking this.

Comment: @vanadium There is no "sda" but "sdb" :) and from the sector numbers in the listing it looks that the partition order is as follows: sdb1-sdb2-sdb3-free space (416M)-sdb6-sdb7-free space (34,4G)-sdb5-sdb4-free space(1,6M). So he needs only to move sdb5 back into the free space and expand it.

Answer (score 0):

That space seems to be located just before `/dev/sdb5` (from your listing, `/dev/sdb5` occupies sectors 395622400 to 467822591, and free space is from 323422208 to 395622399), so it should be possible to use it to extend `/dev/sdb5`.

You should be able to do it by booting from a live Ubuntu media and using GParted program in the live session to move and extend partition.

Of course it is advised to first backup all your important data from that partition to some external drive, in case anything goes wrong.